# Getting Paperclip to upload to S3 in development and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, devise, paperclip

I've been having a rough time trying to get Paperclip to upload images to Amazon S3. Although I got the program working at first, it would only save locally (despite the storage method set to s3) and once I figure out that I needed to override the default paths, it crashes with a write error.

I don't know if it's important, but I'm using Devise and added the `profile_image` to the user model.

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) from Heroku

Here is the first setup that only write locally despite seeming to be setup for S3:

```
user.rb
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_attached_file :profile_image, styles: {
        thumb: '100x100>',
        square: '200x200#',
        medium: '300x300>'
      }
      validates_attachment_content_type :profile_image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

production.rb and development.rb

```
config.paperlip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credientials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION')
    }
  }
  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/local/bin/'
```

portion of the upload form
app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <% if @user.profile_image.present? %>
        <%= image_tag(current_user.profile_image.url(:square)) %><br />
        <%= link_to 'Remove profile image', remove_profile_image_path, method: :put, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, type: 'button' %> 
      <% else %>
        <%= f.label :profile_image %>
        <%= f.file_field :profile_image %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

With this setup, Paperclip works, but it will only save images locally (this is true both in development and deployed on Heroku).

Next, I tried to force the display URL to come form AWS by adding this to

config/initializers/paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

and this does force the image path to come from there (when I refreshed the page for a user who already had an image attached it was broken because there was no image uploaded). However, after I deleted this image, I was not able to upload any more. Every time I try to upload I get this error:

```
Errno::EACCES in Devise::RegistrationsController#update

Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /users/profile_images
```

In an attempt to fix this I added an additional initializer (from Heroku tutorial)

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
```

which didn't work and I tried adding a line to the production.rb and development.rb without success (I tried adding both to the defaults hash and the credentials hash)

```
s3_domain_url: 's3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
```

I understand that the error is a local write error, but my specific questions (in addition to how to do I make this work):

Why is Paperclip ignoring the storage value in the defaults and saving locally (in the first scenario)?
And why is it trying to write to my local disk (in the second scenario) and not uploading to S3?

**Update**
Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.3'

gem 'rails',                   '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
gem 'puma',                    '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier',                '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks',              '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder',                '~> 2.5'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'devise'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'bourbon',                 '5.0.0.beta.7'
gem 'neat',                    '2.0.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass',       '~> 4.7.0'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk',                 '~> 2.3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
  gem 'haml-lint', require: false
end

group :test do
  gem 'guard', '2.13.0'
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.1.9'
  gem 'coveralls', require: false
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~>4.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this is set up in the question and the documentation used is either wrong or no longer valid for `Paperclip ~> 5.1` & `AWS-SDK ~> 2.0` on Heroku.

There is also a second, unstated, problem that will become apparent as soon as this is made to work in development, development uploads will overwrite the production uploads and vice-versa.

This is the setup that worked for me using a development environment and a production environment that both upload to S3.

1. Slim down the initializers to only the shared info

`config/initializers/paperclip.rb`

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ':class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :s3
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_protocol] = 'https'
```

2. Define and valid images and image sizes in the user model

`app/model/users.rb`

```
has_attached_file :profile_image, styles: {
    thumb: '100x100>',
    square: '200x200#',
    medium: '300x300>'
  }
validates_attachment_content_type :profile_image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

3. Register a second dev image bucket and add the necessary variables to the .ENV file

`.ENV`

```
# Shared S3 variables
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

# Development variables
DEV_S3_BUCKET_NAME=your-dev-bucket-name

# Production variables
S3_BUCKET_NAME=your-production-bucket-name
```

4. Put the default options and command path in their respective environments file

`config/environments/development.rb`

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_credentials] = {
    :bucket => ENV['DEV_S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :region => 'us-east-2'
  }
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_region] = 'us-east-2'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'usr/local/bin'
```

In my case I hardcoded the regions and host name, you can extract these if you want. I also chose to host the dev images in a different region just for a little more separation. Also note, the first bucket I created (production) doesn't append the region to the address. I'm not sure why S3 is configured this way, but you can check your specific image path by uploading an image and then drilling down in the folders in AWS Console until you find the image URL.

`config/environments/production.rb`

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_credentials] = {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :region => 'us-east-1'
  }
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_region] = 'us-east-1'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3.amazonaws.com'
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'usr/local/bin'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change the path option from

```
PaperClip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ":rails_root/public/system/.../the/rest/of/the/desired/path"
```

Comment: This does solve the write error, but the images are still saved locally and not uploaded to S3

Comment: Could you post your Gemfile?

Comment: Added at the bottom